# How to place text selection cursor at the beginning of the text field by default when renaming files on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, rename, editing, save-as

I am quite struggling with naming files when I am either saving or renaming them because, initially, the text field is always entirely selected from start to end, so I am virtually forced to either press the **Home** key or **Left click** at the beginning of the line, in order to be able to type from the start of the text field. Since this isn't documented anywhere, I'm very keen to hear anyone's opinion on this matter.

Answer (score 2):

No, I do not believe this is possible in Windows File Explorer (I assume you are using this, you don't say). This is the default and expected behaviour when renaming files - I think in most OS's.

The name is selected but the extension is not as this is considered to be the most common requirement. At least by Microsoft and others.

You should give us more information to go on if you want more specific help - for example, **why** are you commonly wanting the cursor at the start? I can understand wanting it at the end if you are doing manual document management and adding a version number, initials or something else to the end.

If you really need this capability a lot, I would recommend either getting a dedicated file rename tool or using something like AutoHotKey to create a macro assigned to a global hot key.